# How to delete all rows in a footable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, footable

I have a footable that I need to clean. I mean, I need to delete all rows in the footable. Is there any footable function to do that? Or do I need to delete rows one by one?

I tried to reinitialize the table doing this:

```
$('.footable').footable();
```

I also have tried to iterate between the rows like this:

```
var footable = $('table').data('footable');

//This is the problem I don´t know how to get first row in the table.
var row = ??????.parents('tr:first'); 

var next=row.next();
for (var i=0; i<long-1; i++){
  footable.removeRow(next);
  next=row.next();
}
footable.removeRow(row);
```

And my corresponding html source code:

```
<table class="footable footable-loaded">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Cantidad</th>
    <th>Producto</th>
    <th>Precio</th>
    <th>Eliminar</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th id="total">19.5</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: What have you tried already? We don't do your coding for you. That's what not SO's for.

Comment: Can you add the rendered html output of your table? I've got a theory what you looked for. Use the edit button underneath this question.

Comment: @reporter    <table class="footable footable-loaded">
 <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Cantidad</th>
    <th>Producto</th>
    <th>Precio</th>
    <th>Eliminar</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 </tbody>
 <tfoot>
   <tr><th></th>
   <th>Total</th>
   <th id="total">19.5</th>
   <th></th>
 </tr></tfoot>
    </table>

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Is your goal this, that you want click on a link and whit you delete all rows?

Comment: @reporter Yes, the answer below has worked perfectly for me. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete by `removeRows()` function:

```
function removeRows(){
    $(".footable>tbody>tr").each(function(index, elem){
        $(elem).remove();
     });
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8wgbo3r4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
footable.rows.load([])
```